# How to say "I see" in German

Tags: phrase-request

"I see" is a phrase that's used very often in a conversation in English.

> A: How much does the book cost?
>
> B: 50 dollars.
>
> A: I see.

Is there an equivalent in German? I'm quite sure it's not `ich sehe`. And `ich verstehe` doesn't seem appropriate when the thing to understand is very simple information, as in the case of this example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, I would say that the best option is

> Ach so!

I've never heard *Ich sehe*, but *verstehe* could mean *I see* as well:

> –  Mein Wagen war echt teuer
>   –  Wie viel?
>   –  *XY* Tausend Euros, denn es ist ein Mercedes
>   –  Ach so! // verstehe // Aha!

Comment: It's interesting and new to me that you could use `Ich verstehe` in the conversation you gave. I thought `verstehe` would only refer to an understanding of some complex thing, not simple information like that.

Comment: And `Ach so!` sounds like a great phrase. Thanks!

Comment: `Aha` is also a good translation, though AFAIK an English *Aha* is more a doubting, a common reason for misunderstanding when Germans state a German *Aha* when they're speaking English.

Comment: "Ach so" works best if you understand something that you haven't really understood before. In the example given here, @falkb's "aha" is the best choice by far. Had the person asked "WHY is the car so expansive?" then the "ach so" would be perfect.

Comment: Actually, in a verbal context, I've never heard anyone say "Ich verstehe.", but rather just "Verstehe.", though it has a somewhat negative connotation if it's just used like that without a follow-up question or statement.
In general, I'd more agree with Takkats answer. The very neutral meaning of "I see" has no reflection in any german phrase.

Answer (score 10):

There is not a fixed 1:1 translation of *"I see"* to German, as this also depends on the context used.

If it was used in the context given in the example it is fine to use  interjections such as *"Aha"*, *"Ach so"*, *"Oha"*, *"Gut"*, *"Danke"* or the like as an answer but we may also hear a confirming answer like e.g.:

> "So viel?" - *"So wenig?"* - *"Das habe ich (nicht) erwartet."*

The answers will be different in another context. Below just a few possibilities with an exemplatory German counterpart (way from perfect but intended to show possible variations):

1. - A: *The overall customer satisfaction increases with the price of our product*
   - B: *I see, but isnt quality the major factor still?*

   > Translates: *"Ja schon, aber ist die Qualität nicht immer noch der bestimmende Faktor?"*
2. - A: *To open the case you will have to pull the slider at the bottom in addition.*
   - B: *I see! Thank you for the hint.*

   > Translates: *"Jetzt hab ichs kapiert. Danke für den Hinweis!*
3. - A: *You cant upgrade your smart phone because it is too old.*
   - B: *I see. What phones are still supported?*

   > Translates: *"Schade! Welche Handys werden denn noch unterstützt?*

I believe this list could almost endlessly be extended.

Comment: Ach so ........ :)

Comment: Das hab ich auch grad gedacht. Loriot lässt grüßen. Evelyn H. Hat das "Ach so." perfektioniert. In einigen Fällen reicht sogar ein einfaches "Ach ...". Loriot kontert gerne mit "So, so!" - Soviel mehr nonverbaler Inhalt als "I see."